# How to get a string from json array (processing)

Tags: json, processing

I need to get the string from the json array file (GoogleTranslate)

```
for (int i = 0; i <= UserData.size(); i++) {
    println("FORR");
    println(i, UserData.size());
    if(i == UserData.size()){
        println("::::::::::::::::1");
        JSONObject NamePass = UserData.getJSONObject(i-2); //Ошибка
        String PassName = NamePass.getString("pn");
```

```
[
  [{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName1212121"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "11",
    "pn": "22211"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "fedya",
    "pn": "feda111fedya"
  }]
]
```

as a result, namePass should be equal to pn (see the JSONarray file), but when executing the code, the error "JSONArray [3] is not a JSONObject.

Comment: If for example i = 0; and you make 0 - 2, what will be happen ?

Comment: Is this Java? You didn't tag it

Comment: @ADyson I tagged it as Processing, which is indeed a language (I had never heard of it before today :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that look off with your code:

1. `i <= UserData.size();` - array/list indices start at 0 in Processing/java. The `=` condition will get you at an index that out of bounds in relation to the list size
2. `UserData.getJSONObject(i-2);` - `i-2` will evaluate to `-2` and `-1` for the first two iterations in the for loop, both indices being outside of bounds (0-3 in your case)
3. There is no need to nest a single object in a single array element in your JSON data.

For example:

```
[{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  }],
```

might as well be this:

```
{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  },
```

if there are no other siblings elements.

Minor note: you should use uppercase for the first character of class names and lower case for the first character of the instance, as per [Java Coding Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). (e.g. `userData`,`namePass`,`passName`)
It makes the code much easier to read and predict.

To traverse data you have I'd first simplify the JSON structure a bit:

```
[
  {
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  },
  {
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName1212121"
  },
  {
    "name": "11",
    "pn": "22211"
  },
  {
    "name": "fedya",
    "pn": "feda111fedya"
  }
]
```

Then simply load/iterate through data (no need for any complex indexing):

```
// load the data
JSONArray data = loadJSONArray("/path/to/your/data.json");

// iterate through the data
for(int i = 0 ; i < data.size(); i++){
  // access each user object
  JSONObject user = data.getJSONObject(i);
  // extract each property from that object
  String name = user.getString("name");
  String pn   = user.getString("pn");
  // test/print data
  println("data[" + i + "] = " + user.format(-1) + " -> name = " + name + " , pn = " + pn); 
}
```

You are very close, however, I believe the confusion stems from your current JSON format where you have an object nested in an array that you might have missed.

e.g.

```
JSONObject NamePass = UserData.getJSONObject(i-2);
```

should've been:

```
// access the i-th array within the top level array, and extract the first object within that
JSONObject namePass = UserData.getJSONArray(i).getJSONObject(0);
```

For more info check out there reference (and play with the example code provided) for [JSONArray](https://processing.org/reference/JSONArray.html) and [JSONObject](https://processing.org/reference/JSONObject.html)

If it helps here's an in illustration using JavaScript instead of Java.
Using your current data:

```js
userData = [
  [{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName1212121"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "11",
    "pn": "22211"
  }],
  [{
    "name": "fedya",
    "pn": "feda111fedya"
  }]
];
// iterate through the main array
for(let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
  // print the index 
 console.log(i,'/',userData.length-1);
  // access the array that contains the object first, then the first (and only) element
 let user = userData[i][0];
  // access object property
 console.log(user.pn);
}
```

Removing an array layer:

```js
userData = [
  {
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName"
  },
  {
    "name": "userName",
    "pn": "Password + userName1212121"
  },
  {
    "name": "11",
    "pn": "22211"
  },
  {
    "name": "fedya",
    "pn": "feda111fedya"
  }
];
// iterate through the main array
for(let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
  // print the index 
 console.log(i,'/',userData.length-1);
  // access the object directly
 let user = userData[i];
  // access object property
 console.log(user.pn);
}
```